# Compiling error c++ with QXmlDefaultHandler in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I think this problem is just simple but I am not really familiar how to setup my environment because someone did it for me. I think it has something to do with the Makefile. Pardon my ignorance for this. I am not using the Qt IDE. The error I encountered is this:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/qt4   -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
xxml.h:4:30: fatal error: QXmlDefaultHandler: No such file or directory
 #include <QXmlDefaultHandler>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

my xxml.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef XXML_H
#define XXML_H

#include <QXmlDefaultHandler>

class XXml : public QXmlDefaultHandler
{
public:
    XXml();
    virtual ~XXml();
    bool startElement(const QString &, const QString &, const QString &, 
                        const QXmlAttributes &);

private:    

};

#endif
```

Makefile:

```
TARGET=x
OBJS=main.o xxml.o
QT_LIBS=-lQtGui -lQtCore
QT_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
QT_INCDIR=/usr/include/qt4

CXXFLAGS=-I $(QT_INCDIR)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    g++ $^ -L $(QT_LIBDIR) $(QT_LIBS) -lpthread -o $@

moc_%.cpp: %.h
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/moc -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Normally you would just add `QT += xml` to the pro file. So you need to work out what that triggers `qmake` to do for the generated makefile and do the same for your own. Out of curiosity, why are you writing your own makefile?

Comment: Hi cmannett85, yeah, I know that simply adding `Qt += xml` to the project file would do the trick but I am compiling it with my own makefile. I am writing my own makefile so I wouldn't depend on Qt IDE. Sorry, but we were encouraged to compile it the harder way so we could see what's happening underneath the codes. Do you have any idea how to make things work in Makefiles?

Comment: Just create a bare minimum Qt project, include the `xml` module, run `qmake`, and look at the make file it produces.

Comment: Strangely, I am encountering problems on creating it on Qt Creator and I think this would need another thread to solve this problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the missing header file by

```
find /usr/include/qt4 -iname '*QXmlDefaultHandler*'
```

The output will be something like

> /usr/include/qt4/QtXml/QXmlDefaultHandler

As you see, the header file is in a subdirectory called `QtXml`. When you prefix the include, it should compile, e.g.

```
#include <QtXml/QXmlDefaultHandler>
```

---

`QXmlDefaultHandler` belongs to `QtXml`. To resolve the linker error, you must add the appropriate libraries to `QT_LIBS`. To find out which are needed, say

```
pkg-config --libs QtXml
```

which will show you

> -lQtXml -lQtCore

You alread have `libQtCore`, so just add `-lQtXml` to the front

```
QT_LIBS=-lQtXml -lQtGui -lQtCore
```

---

As @MykhayloKopytonenko suggested, it is better to add the appropriate include paths. `pkg-config` delivers the necessary compiler flags for this as well, just enter

```
pkg-config --cflags QtXml
```

and you get (at least on my system)

> -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXml -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore

To add this to your Makefile

```
QT_CFLAGS = -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXml -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore
CXXFLAGS = $(QT_CFLAGS)
```

If you want just the include flags, use `--cflags-only-I` instead

```
pkg-config --cflags-only-I QtXml
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, I get your point that it is under `#include <QtXml>` I think I'm almost near there but I encountered a lot of errors.


`g++ main.o xxml.o -L /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -o x
xxml.o: In function `QXmlDefaultHandler::QXmlDefaultHandler()':
xxml.cpp:(.text._ZN18QXmlDefaultHandlerC2Ev[_ZN18QXmlDefaultHandlerC5Ev]+0x5c): undefined reference to `vtable for QXmlDefaultHandler'
xxml.cpp:(.text._ZN18QXmlDefaultHandlerC2Ev[_ZN18QXmlDefaultHandlerC5Ev]+0x7a): undefined reference to `vtable for QXmlDefaultHandler'`

Comment: Well, this is a different (linker) error, see updated answer.

Comment: BTW, "almost near there" and "a lot of errors", usually don't go hand in hand. ;-)

Comment: yeah you're right, but I think adding something like that in the header is a good start so I said that I am near :p

Comment: Using `QtXml` path in the include, `#include <QtXml/QXmlDefaultHandler>`, is not a good style. Usually, all Qt4 headers are included without the module name: `#include <QXmlDefaultHandler>`, and the module subdirectory is added to the include path: `CXXFLAGS=-I /usr/include/qt4 -I /usr/include/qt4/QtXml -I /usr/include/qt4/QtCore`.

Comment: That is a better explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it!

adding `#include <QtXml/QXmlDefaultHandler>` on xxml.h
and adding `-lQtXml` on `QT_LIBS` on Makefile did the trick.

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: consider to do `qt += xml`. it should add the libraries needed as well as add `<QtDir>/include/QtXml` to your project

Comment: yes but it is unclear for me how it all works together. he does not want to depend on QtCreator but uses moc so it would also allow to us qmake instead of make